# How Use custom webfonts (woff,woff2) in Figma

Tags: fonts, figma

Is there any way to import custom webfonts into Figma desktop app, e.g. from some CDN or using woff/woff2 source files?

Convertion to other font types seems to be a workaround, but it’s not quite reliable due to possible conversion losses and distortions.